# Boost performance buffer application [Xillybus - VHDL]

Tags: fpga, vhdl

In this previous question [link](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/208421/copy-data-into-read-device-file-after-eof-from-input-text-xillybus-vhdl) I had developed an application that sequentially did:

1. get and store 8 input values (8 characters)
2. swap upper to lower (or vice versa) case only the first char
3. output the eight characters

The problem is that it is too slow and I have to speed up the total execution time. I guess the problem is that the application performs the points 1, 2 and 3 sequentially. In order to improve the performance I guess I should parallelize the write and read operation.

**USING 2 FIFOs version 2:** as suggested in the comment I have to implement 2 FIFOs. If my understanding is correct the first FIFO is used to write data from PCI to FIFO and the second FIFO is used to copy data from FPGA to PCI. Thus the application should performs the following steps:

- as soon as data is on write_device_file store it into `STD_FIFO_WRITE`
- swap upper to lower (or vice versa) case only the first char
- as soon as data is ready, write it into `STD_FIFO_READ`

As solution to this problem I used the FIFO from this [link](http://www.deathbylogic.com/2013/07/vhdl-standard-fifo/). Here the code (STD_FIFO.vhd):

```
library IEEE;
USE IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
USE IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

entity STD_FIFO is
Generic (
    constant DATA_WIDTH  : positive := 8;
    constant FIFO_DEPTH : positive := 256
);
Port ( 
    CLK     : in  STD_LOGIC;
    RST     : in  STD_LOGIC;
    WriteEn : in  STD_LOGIC;
    DataIn  : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (DATA_WIDTH - 1 downto 0);
    ReadEn  : in  STD_LOGIC;
    DataOut : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (DATA_WIDTH - 1 downto 0);
    Empty   : out STD_LOGIC;
    Full    : out STD_LOGIC
);
end STD_FIFO;

architecture Behavioral of STD_FIFO is

begin

-- Memory Pointer Process
fifo_proc : process (CLK)
    type FIFO_Memory is array (0 to FIFO_DEPTH - 1) of STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (DATA_WIDTH - 1 downto 0);
    variable Memory : FIFO_Memory;

    variable Head : natural range 0 to FIFO_DEPTH - 1;
    variable Tail : natural range 0 to FIFO_DEPTH - 1;

    variable Looped : boolean;
begin
    if rising_edge(CLK) then
        if RST = '1' then
            Head := 0;
            Tail := 0;

            Looped := false;

            Full  <= '0';
            Empty <= '1';
        else
            if (ReadEn = '1') then
                if ((Looped = true) or (Head /= Tail)) then
                    -- Update data output
                    DataOut <= Memory(Tail);

                    -- Update Tail pointer as needed
                    if (Tail = FIFO_DEPTH - 1) then
                        Tail := 0;

                        Looped := false;
                    else
                        Tail := Tail + 1;
                    end if;


                end if;
            end if;

            if (WriteEn = '1') then
                if ((Looped = false) or (Head /= Tail)) then
                    -- Write Data to Memory
                    Memory(Head) := DataIn;

                    -- Increment Head pointer as needed
                    if (Head = FIFO_DEPTH - 1) then
                        Head := 0;

                        Looped := true;
                    else
                        Head := Head + 1;
                    end if;
                end if;
            end if;

            -- Update Empty and Full flags
            if (Head = Tail) then
                if Looped then
                    Full <= '1';
                else
                    Empty <= '1';
                end if;
            else
                Empty   <= '0';
                Full    <= '0';
            end if;
        end if;
    end if;
end process;

end Behavioral;
```

In this [link](http://www.spacewire.co.uk/auto_fifo.html) I understood that it is not possible to connect the FIFOs in this way: [image: FIFOs problem] 
because of possible problem of handshake mechanism. As workaround, the previous link provides the VHDL code to convert a standard dual port FIFO into an Autonomous Cascadable Dual Port FIFO:
[image: Autonomous Cascadable Dual Port FIFO]

The VHDL code of the Autonomous Cascadable Dual Port FIFO is ac_fifo_wrap.vhd (in which I have already included the `STD_FIFO`):

```
LIBRARY IEEE;
USE IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

ENTITY ac_fifo_wrap IS
GENERIC(
      --== Data Width ==--
      data_width : NATURAL := 8
     );
  PORT(
   --==  General Interface ==--
   rst    : IN  STD_LOGIC;
   clk    : IN  STD_LOGIC;

   --== Input Interface ==--
   nwrite : IN  STD_LOGIC;
   full   : OUT STD_LOGIC;
   din    : IN  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(data_width-1 DOWNTO 0);

   --== Output Interface ==--
   empty  : OUT STD_LOGIC;
   nread  : IN  STD_LOGIC;
   dout   : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(data_width-1 DOWNTO 0)
  );
END ac_fifo_wrap;


ARCHITECTURE rtl OF ac_fifo_wrap IS

---==========================---
--== Component Declarations ==--
---==========================---


component STD_FIFO
port (
  CLK: IN std_logic;
  RST: IN std_logic;
  WriteEn: IN std_logic;
  DataIn: IN std_logic_VECTOR(7 downto 0);
  ReadEn: IN std_logic;
  DataOut: OUT std_logic_VECTOR(7 downto 0);
  Empty: OUT std_logic;
  Full: OUT std_logic
);
end component;

---=======================---
--== Signal Declarations ==--
---=======================---

SIGNAL empty_int : STD_LOGIC;
SIGNAL empty_i   : STD_LOGIC;
SIGNAL full_i    : STD_LOGIC;
SIGNAL rd_en     : STD_LOGIC;
SIGNAL wr_en     : STD_LOGIC;

BEGIN

  ---====================---
  --== FIFO write logic ==--
  ---====================---

  wr_en <= NOT(full_i) AND NOT(nwrite);

  full <= full_i;

  ---================================---
  --== STD_FIFO (CoreGen Module) ==--
  ---================================---

  -- CPU to FPGA FIFO
  U0: STD_FIFO
  port map(
    RST       => rst,
    CLK       => clk,
    WriteEn    => wr_en,
    Full      => full_i,
    DataIn       => din,
    Empty     => empty_int,
    ReadEn     => rd_en,
    DataOut      => dout
  );


  ---===================---
  --== FIFO read logic ==--
  ---===================---

  rd_en <= NOT(empty_int) AND (empty_i OR NOT(nread));

  PROCESS(clk)
  BEGIN
IF RISING_EDGE(clk) THEN
  IF (rst = '1') THEN
    empty_i <= '1';
  ELSE
    empty_i <= empty_int AND (empty_i OR NOT(nread));
  END IF;
END IF;
  END PROCESS;

  empty <= empty_i;

END rtl;
```

**What I have done:**

in `ac_fifo_wrap` I defined the component `STD_FIFO`. In this way I connected Autonomous Cascadable Dual Port FIFO (`ac_fifo_wrap`) with the dual port FIFO (`STD_FIFO`).

In `xillydemo.vhd` I defined 2 ac_fifo_wrap, `ac_fifo_wrap_write` and `ac_fifo_wrap_read` respectively. In this way I have 2 FIFOs connected and I should not have handshake problem. Here `xillydemo.vhd`:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity xillydemo is
  port (
PCIE_PERST_B_LS : IN std_logic;
PCIE_REFCLK_N : IN std_logic;
PCIE_REFCLK_P : IN std_logic;
PCIE_RX_N : IN std_logic_vector(3 DOWNTO 0);
PCIE_RX_P : IN std_logic_vector(3 DOWNTO 0);
GPIO_LED : OUT std_logic_vector(3 DOWNTO 0);
PCIE_TX_N : OUT std_logic_vector(3 DOWNTO 0);
PCIE_TX_P : OUT std_logic_vector(3 DOWNTO 0));
end xillydemo;

architecture sample_arch of xillydemo is
  component xillybus
port (
  PCIE_PERST_B_LS : IN std_logic;
  PCIE_REFCLK_N : IN std_logic;
  PCIE_REFCLK_P : IN std_logic;
  PCIE_RX_N : IN std_logic_vector(3 DOWNTO 0);
  PCIE_RX_P : IN std_logic_vector(3 DOWNTO 0);
  GPIO_LED : OUT std_logic_vector(3 DOWNTO 0);
  PCIE_TX_N : OUT std_logic_vector(3 DOWNTO 0);
  PCIE_TX_P : OUT std_logic_vector(3 DOWNTO 0);
  bus_clk : OUT std_logic;
  quiesce : OUT std_logic;

  user_r_read_8_rden : OUT std_logic;
  user_r_read_8_empty : IN std_logic;
  user_r_read_8_data : IN std_logic_vector(7 DOWNTO 0);
  user_r_read_8_eof : IN std_logic;
  user_r_read_8_open : OUT std_logic;
  user_w_write_8_wren : OUT std_logic;
  user_w_write_8_full : IN std_logic;
  user_w_write_8_data : OUT std_logic_vector(7 DOWNTO 0);
  user_w_write_8_open : OUT std_logic);
  end component;


component ac_fifo_wrap
port (
  --==  General Interface ==--
  RST: IN std_logic;
  CLK: IN std_logic;

  --== Input Interface ==--
  nwrite: IN std_logic;
  full: OUT std_logic;
  din: IN std_logic_VECTOR(7 downto 0);

  --== Output Interface ==--
  empty: OUT std_logic;
  nread: IN std_logic;
  dout: OUT std_logic_VECTOR(7 downto 0) 
);
end component;


  signal bus_clk :  std_logic;
  signal quiesce : std_logic;

  signal reset_8 : std_logic;

  signal user_r_read_8_rden :  std_logic;
  signal user_r_read_8_empty :  std_logic;
  signal user_r_read_8_data :  std_logic_vector(7 DOWNTO 0);
  signal user_r_read_8_eof :  std_logic;
  signal user_r_read_8_open :  std_logic;

  signal user_w_write_8_wren :  std_logic;
  signal user_w_write_8_full :  std_logic;
  signal user_w_write_8_data :  std_logic_vector(7 DOWNTO 0);
  signal user_w_write_8_open :  std_logic;

  signal s_dout_din : std_logic_vector(7 DOWNTO 0);
  signal s_nread_full :  std_logic;
  signal s_empty_nwrite :  std_logic;

begin
  xillybus_ins : xillybus
port map (


  -- Ports related to /dev/xillybus_read_8
  -- FPGA to CPU signals:
  user_r_read_8_rden => user_r_read_8_rden,
  user_r_read_8_empty => user_r_read_8_empty,
  user_r_read_8_data => user_r_read_8_data,
  user_r_read_8_eof => user_r_read_8_eof,
  user_r_read_8_open => user_r_read_8_open,

  -- Ports related to /dev/xillybus_write_8
  -- CPU to FPGA signals:
  user_w_write_8_wren => user_w_write_8_wren,
  user_w_write_8_full => user_w_write_8_full,
  user_w_write_8_data => user_w_write_8_data,
  user_w_write_8_open => user_w_write_8_open,

  -- General signals
  PCIE_PERST_B_LS => PCIE_PERST_B_LS,
  PCIE_REFCLK_N => PCIE_REFCLK_N,
  PCIE_REFCLK_P => PCIE_REFCLK_P,
  PCIE_RX_N => PCIE_RX_N,
  PCIE_RX_P => PCIE_RX_P,
  GPIO_LED => GPIO_LED,
  PCIE_TX_N => PCIE_TX_N,
  PCIE_TX_P => PCIE_TX_P,
  bus_clk => bus_clk,
  quiesce => quiesce
  );


-- CPU to FPGA FIFO
ac_fifo_wrap_write: ac_fifo_wrap
port map(
  RST       => reset_8,
  CLK       => bus_clk,
  nwrite    => not user_w_write_8_wren,
  full      => user_w_write_8_full,
  din       => user_w_write_8_data,
  empty     => s_empty_nwrite, --
  nread     => s_nread_full, --
  dout      => s_dout_din--
);

-- FPGA to CPU FIFO  
ac_fifo_wrap_read: ac_fifo_wrap
  port map(
RST       => reset_8,
CLK       => bus_clk,
nwrite    => s_empty_nwrite, --
full      => s_nread_full, --
din       => s_dout_din, --
empty     => user_r_read_8_empty,
nread     => not user_r_read_8_rden,
dout      => user_r_read_8_data
  );


-- these lines must be preserved in the XillyDemo
reset_8 <= not (user_w_write_8_open or user_r_read_8_open);
user_r_read_8_eof <= user_r_read_8_empty and not(user_w_write_8_open);

end sample_arch;
```

**Problem:** Now I have to test my code and I wrote this test bench based on the one suggested by @MartinZabel. Well, I adapted the test bench suggested to this version. The thing is that I need to test 2 `ac_fifo_wrap` together, because the first `ac_fifo_wrap` should simulate the data writing from PCI to FIFO and the second `ac_fifo_wrap` should simulate the data writing from FPGA to PCI. Here, my test bench used for testing 2 `ac_fifo_wrap` together. Is it ok?

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity ac_fifo_wrap_tb is
end ac_fifo_wrap_tb;

architecture sim of ac_fifo_wrap_tb is

component ac_fifo_wrap
port (
  --==  General Interface ==--
  RST: IN std_logic;
  CLK: IN std_logic;

  --== Input Interface ==--
  nwrite: IN std_logic;
  full: OUT std_logic;
  din: IN std_logic_VECTOR(7 downto 0);

  --== Output Interface ==--
  empty: OUT std_logic;
  nread: IN std_logic;
  dout: OUT std_logic_VECTOR(7 downto 0) 
);
end component;

  signal bus_clk             : std_logic := '1';
  signal reset_8             : std_logic;
  signal user_w_write_8_wren : std_logic;
  signal user_w_write_8_full : std_logic;
  signal user_w_write_8_data : std_logic_vector(7 DOWNTO 0);
  signal user_r_read_8_rden  : std_logic;
  signal user_r_read_8_empty : std_logic;
  signal user_r_read_8_data  : std_logic_vector(7 DOWNTO 0);

  signal s_dout_din : std_logic_vector(7 DOWNTO 0);
  signal s_nread_full :  std_logic;
  signal s_empty_nwrite :  std_logic;


begin
  -- component instantiation
  DUT_write: entity work.ac_fifo_wrap
port map (
  RST       => reset_8,
  CLK       => bus_clk,
  nwrite    => not user_w_write_8_wren,
  full      => user_w_write_8_full,
  din       => user_w_write_8_data,
  empty     => s_empty_nwrite, --
  nread     => s_nread_full, --
  dout      => s_dout_din
);

  -- component instantiation
  DUT_read: entity work.ac_fifo_wrap
port map (
    RST       => reset_8,
    CLK       => bus_clk,
    nwrite    => s_empty_nwrite, --
    full      => s_nread_full, --
    din       => s_dout_din, --
    empty     => user_r_read_8_empty,
    nread     => not user_r_read_8_rden,
    dout      => user_r_read_8_data
);     



  -- clock generation
  bus_clk <= not bus_clk after 5 ns;

  -- waveform generation
  WaveGen_Proc: process
  begin
        reset_8  <= '1';                     -- apply reset
        -- other input values don't care during reset
        wait until rising_edge(bus_clk);

        -- Endless idle cycles
        reset_8 <= '0';
        user_w_write_8_wren <= '0';
        user_w_write_8_data <= (others => '-');
        user_r_read_8_rden  <= '0';
        wait;
  end process WaveGen_Proc;
end sim;
```

Comment: "too slow" is too vague. How long does it take and how long do you need it to take? Do you have any evidence the hardware speed is even observable, compared with the program that writes raw data and reads processed data? At a wild guess, it's the I/O program that takes the time...

Comment: too slow means that it takes 25000 millisecond to analyze a 10 MB text file. I developed a Java application that does the same steps as the one I developed in VHDL and the Java one is faster. Moreover, in the past I developed an application that swapped all characters from uppercase to lowercase and viceversa (with xillybus) and I/O did not take the time. Thus, I guess if I parallelize the read and write operations I shoud reduce the total execution time.

Comment: Your 'circular array' is what I suggested by using a FIFO at your last question. I suggest to use a ready to use FIFO instead of your own, unless you want to go through the pitfalls of designing a correct FIFO.

Comment: The PCIe / XillyBus overhead is much bigger then transforming some bytes in the FPGA. And don't forget the kernel overhead!

Comment: @Paebbels in the other question you suggested to use 2 fifo, one for reading and the other one for writing. How may I use to different fifo in order to solve thus task? Well, the fifo should be only one because I store and then I get that data.

Comment: You need 2 FIFOs. One to receive data from PCI, and one to store data to send to PCI. In between you have your logic to convert to uppercase. As long as the receive FIFO has room available, you perform PCI read (or write, depending who controls). Similarly, as long as you have data on the transmit FIFOs, you perform PCI write. Everything has to work concurently.

Comment: @JonathanDrolet I connected 2 FIFOs and now I should not have handshake problem anymore. You suggested me _to put in between the your logic to convert to uppercase._ What do you exactly mean? Should I have to write the logic in one of the FIFO (e.g. as soon as data is in the first FIFO, convert upper to lower case and then send it to second FIFO) or should I have to create a new vhd file and write the logic there?

Comment: Why do you write the FIFO logic yourself? You're clearly a beginner, so use your vendor's tool to create a FIFO, there are many gotchas when it comes to frequency differences. Put your logic into its own entity and write a separate test bench for it. Use a FIFO-style interface (din, dout, synchronous reset) with latency of one clock cycle. Remember that you don't need to store 8 chars, you can just count.

Comment: @FRob I added from the IP catalog (Vivado 2015) the `FIFO generator` and I use it instead of `STD_FIFO`. During the IP customization I set `Read width` and `Write width` to 8. You suggested me to use it _with latency of one clock cycle._ How do I set that value? In the parameter summary I only see _Read Latency (From rising edge of Read clock): 1_. Is this parameter what you meant? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**Note**: This answer only applies to the [original version](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/revisions/209270/1)  of the question.

Your design does not work because after `reset_8` is de-asserted by XillyBus (i.e. goes low), your unit never sets `user_w_write_8_full` to low to indicate that it is ready to receive data.

The shortest possible testbench to check this is:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity my_buffer_tb is
end my_buffer_tb;

architecture sim of my_buffer_tb is
  signal bus_clk             : std_logic := '1';
  signal reset_8             : std_logic;
  signal user_w_write_8_wren : std_logic;
  signal user_w_write_8_full : std_logic;
  signal user_w_write_8_data : std_logic_vector(7 DOWNTO 0);
  signal user_r_read_8_rden  : std_logic;
  signal user_r_read_8_empty : std_logic;
  signal user_r_read_8_data  : std_logic_vector(7 DOWNTO 0);
begin
  -- component instantiation
  DUT: entity work.my_buffer
    port map (
      bus_clk             => bus_clk,
      reset_8             => reset_8,
      user_w_write_8_wren => user_w_write_8_wren,
      user_w_write_8_full => user_w_write_8_full,
      user_w_write_8_data => user_w_write_8_data,
      user_r_read_8_rden  => user_r_read_8_rden,
      user_r_read_8_empty => user_r_read_8_empty,
      user_r_read_8_data  => user_r_read_8_data);

  -- clock generation
  bus_clk <= not bus_clk after 5 ns;

  -- waveform generation
  WaveGen_Proc: process
  begin
    reset_8 <= '1';                     -- apply reset
    -- other input values don't care during reset
    wait until rising_edge(bus_clk);

    -- Endless idle cycles
    reset_8 <= '0';
    user_w_write_8_wren <= '0';
    user_w_write_8_data <= (others => '-');
    user_r_read_8_rden  <= '0';
    wait;
  end process WaveGen_Proc;
end sim;
```

The corresponding simulation output is as follows. As you see, after `reset` is de-asserted at 10 ns, the `full` keeps high and never goes low. Thus, XillyBus does not send you any data.

[image: simulation output]

You haven't posted your testbench and/or simulation output yet, but I think, you missed to check if `full` is even going to low.

Comment: I improved the code. Now I have 2 FIFOs connected and I should not have problem of handshake. As next step I have to test my application. The test bench I wrote is based on the one you wrote but it does not work. I think there are problems with signals in my test bench. Where am I wrong?

Comment: @MessagePassing I have to take a closer look, but what I have seen so far: The `nread` and `nwrite` signals of `ac_fifo_wrap` are active-low, i.e., data is read or written if these control signals are low instead of high. But, the `rden` and `wren` of XillyBus are active-high, so you have to negate them first.